# Выпадает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: options.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Применяю этот компонент в другом, и там ошибка в консоли Uncaught TypeError: options.map is not a function

введите сюда код

```js
export const CustomSelect = ({ id, options, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <select className="custom-select" id={id} onChange={onChange}>
            {options.map((option) =>
            <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>,
            )}
        </select>
    );
};
```

введите сюда код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотри в консили тебе точно массив приходит сначало , если не поможет поставь проверку  перед options

```
export const CustomSelect = ({ id, options, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <select className="custom-select" id={id} onChange={onChange}>
            {options && options.map((option) =>
            <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>,
            )}
        </select>
    );
};
```